# R: Turning row into columns with NA entries (error using tidyr: spread)

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, reshape, melt

I've the following dataset

| Pet Shop | Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | dog | 300 |
| A | fish | 20 |
| A | turtle | 50 |
| A | dog | 250 |
| A | cat | 280 |
| A | rabbit | 180 |
| A | cat | 270 |
| B | dog | 350 |
| B | fish | 70 |
| B | cat | 220 |
| B | turtle | 80 |
| B | fish | 55 |
| B | fish | 75 |
| C | dog | 280 |
| C | cat | 260 |
| C | fish | 65 |

The code for the data is as follows

```
Pet_Shop = c(rep("A",7), rep("B",6), rep("C",3))
Item = c("Dog","Fish","Turtle","Dog","Cat","Rabbit","Cat","Dog","Fish","Cat","Turtle","Fish","Fish","Dog","Cat","Fish")
Price = c(300,20,50,250,280,180,270,350,70,220,80,55,75,280,260,65)
Data = data.frame(Pet_Shop, Item, Price)
```

I'm trying to change the data into the following table

[image: Output Dataframe]

Does anyone know how to do this? I tried doing the following method using spread but it returns an error

```
Test = spread(Data, Item, Price)
```

> ```
> Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
> Keys are shared for 7 rows:
> * 5, 7
> * 1, 4
> * 9, 12, 13
> ```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this work? `Data$id <- seq_len(nrow(Data)); Data <- spread(Data, Item, Price); Data$id <- NULL`

Comment: Thank you! did not occur to me that an ID row is needed, appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you're looking for. Note `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` are the new `dplyr` versions of `spread` and `gather`, respectively. The issue was that you needed to create a unique identifier row for each name before transforming.

```
new_data <- Data %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Item, values_from = Price) %>%
  select(-row)
```

Output:

```
   Pet_Shop   Dog  Fish Turtle   Cat Rabbit
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A          300    NA     NA    NA     NA
 2 A           NA    20     NA    NA     NA
 3 A           NA    NA     50    NA     NA
 4 A          250    NA     NA    NA     NA
 5 A           NA    NA     NA   280     NA
 6 A           NA    NA     NA    NA    180
 7 A           NA    NA     NA   270     NA
 8 B          350    NA     NA    NA     NA
 9 B           NA    70     NA    NA     NA
10 B           NA    NA     NA   220     NA
11 B           NA    NA     80    NA     NA
12 B           NA    55     NA    NA     NA
13 B           NA    75     NA    NA     NA
14 C          280    NA     NA    NA     NA
15 C           NA    NA     NA   260     NA
16 C           NA    65     NA    NA     NA
```